# Finding Curve to Minimize Polynomial over Unit Cube

Tags: multivariable-calculus, calculus-of-variations, multivariate-polynomial

You are given an $n$-variable multilinear polynomial (can assume of degree 2 if it helps) from an $n$-dimentional cube $p:[-1,1]^n\to\mathbb{R}$ and two vertices $v,u\in\{-1,1\}^n$. Our goal is to find a curve $\gamma: [0,1] \to [-1,1]^n$ between $u$ and $v$ which maximizes $\min_{t\in[0,1]}{p\big(\gamma(t)\big)}$.

For now, I am not even sure what fields should I consider and study before approaching this question and I would appreciate any help and directions.

Thank you all for your help in advance.

**Note:** After viewing that nothing helpful can be said on general polynomials, I've edited the question to be on multilinear ones.

Comment: Considering the level surfaces of the polynomial function will surely help.

Comment: You use $t \in \{-1,1\}^n$ and $t \in [0,1]$ which is confusing. I would recommend using a different variable name, maybe $s_1$ and $s_2$ or $v$ and $u$ for the vertices. Find the minimum value of $p$ and then use a piecewise linear function to first go to the point where it reaches that minimum and the to the other vertex. Then the minimum on the path will be the minimum of the polynomial and cannot be improved.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Changed $s,t$ to $u,v$, this is indeed confusing, thank you! :) As for your solution, I am trying to **maximize** the minimum point, so I am hoping to do better than going through the minimum point on $p$.

Comment: Since $\max \min_{t \in [0,1]} p(\gamma(t)) \leq \min \{p(u),p(v)\}$ we can follow the gradient between the levels sets $p(x)=p(u)$ and $p(x)=p(v)$ and then follow the level curve $p(x)=p(v)$ to get a curve which gives you $\max \min_{t \in [0,1]} p(\gamma(t)) = \min \{p(u),p(v)\}$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField this is not always true, it is possible that both $u$ and $v$ be local maxima, in which case this approach won’t work

Comment: Also, @ShaharRomemPeled, what kind of answer are you hoping for? Just the existence of such a path, an algorithm for a compute to approximate it, and precise description of how to obtain it? I’m guessing it might be quite hard to describe $\gamma$ in general

Comment: @RomainS I was hoping for an algorithm which yields an approximation, something like a $0.5$-approximation (i.e. $\min_{t\in[0,1]}{p\big(\gamma(t)\big)} \geq 0.5\min\{p(u),p(v)\}$).
I am also pretty sure that you can come up with simple examples that proves that one cannot achieve anything better than a $0.5$-approximation.

Answer (score 1):

Your hope to achieve $\min_t p(\gamma(t))\geq 0.5\min\{p(u),p(v)\}$ is unfortunately impossible: even when $n=1$ with $u=-1, v=1$, we can force $\min_t p(\gamma(t))$ to be as small as we want regardless of $p(u)$ and $p(v)$ by considering $p(x)=a(x-1)(x+1)$ for $a$ arbitrarily large (since $p(0)=-a$, but $p(u)=p(v)=0$). This example can easily be generalized to any dimension.

Furthermore, a path $\gamma$ which maximizes $\min_t p(\gamma(t))$ may not even always exist. Let $\mathcal{C}$ denote the set of curves $\gamma\colon [0,1]\to [-1,1]^n$ with $\gamma(0)=u$, $\gamma(1)=v$, and consider the function $f\colon \mathcal{C}\to\mathbb{R}$ taking $\gamma\to\min_t p(\gamma(t))$. With the metric $d(\gamma, \theta)=\sup_t|\gamma(t),\theta(t)|$, $f$ is continuous, but $C$ is not compact, so it is not guaranteed that $f$ will achieve its supremum (although there may be another way to approach this problem).

Finally, if you are simply looking to find an algorithm to approximate such a curve, I would consider taking a straight line from $u$ to $v$, and then moving each $\gamma(t)$ along the gradient at that point for each time step (in a similar fashion to what @CyclotomicField suggested). It might be worth adjusting the size of your time steps according to the degree of $p$.

**Edit**: As suggested in the comment, consider the case when $p(x)$ is multilinear, writing $p(x)=a_1x_1+\dots+a_nx_n+c$. We claim that, in this case, taking $\gamma$ to be the straight line between $u$ and $v$ will yield precisely $\min_tp(\gamma(t))=\min\{p(u),p(v)\}$. Indeed, let $\gamma(t)=t\cdot u+(1-t)\cdot v$. Then,
$$p(\gamma(t))=c+\sum_{k=1}^na_k\left(tu_k+(1-t)v_k\right),$$
which is a linear function in $t$, and hence must reach its minimum on $[0,1]$ at one of the endpoints.

Comment: Thanks! If not general polynomials, what about multilinear functions? For one dimension this is trivial, but what about more?

Comment: @ShaharRomemPeled I have edited my answer, does this help? Let me know if you have any further questions

Comment: Oh, by multilinear I meant linear on each variable, so $x_1 x_2 x_3$ is also multilinear. Hence, your solution unfortunately doesn't work in this case.